# await-for not finishing for Stream

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I'm mapping a Stream from a Firestore collection and am using await-for to iterate through it, but the loop never finishes.

Here's my function that returns a Stream<List>

```
  final _userGroups = Firestore.instance.collection('groups');

  Stream<List<String>> getGroupNames() {
    Stream<QuerySnapshot> snapshots = _userGroups.snapshots();

    return snapshots.map((snapshot) => snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
          return doc.data['name'].toString();
        }).toList());
  }
```

And my simple test function that uses await-for to count the items returned in the Stream (my real use case is more complex, but testing my sanity here).

```
  final _userGroups = Firestore.instance.collection('groups');

  Future<int> getUserGroupCount() async {
    int count;
    final groupNamesStream = getGroupNames();
    try {
      await for (var groupNames in groupNamesStream) {
        for (var groupName in groupNames) {
          count++;
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return count;
    }

    return count;
  }
```

No exception is thrown. The weird part is even if the groupNames list has two items, its loop only iterates once. (the count++ breakpoint is only reached once.)

Using the debugger, I hover over the values and the all look great. No errors in the debug console.

I'm new to streams, so may be missing something obvious?

Comment: `await for` will wait until the `Stream` closes. In your case you really don't need to use `Stream`s at all it seems.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore, I see. But for my simple test, why would `count++` only execute once if `groupNames` contained 2 or more items?

Comment: I don't know about that. That would be odd if `groupNames` really does contain more than a single item.

Comment: await Stream.toList();??